# Foreign key violation with order_inserts=true and batches with mixed subclass entities

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, batch-processing, hibernate-mapping

### Problem

Hibernate inserts the entities in the wrong order when **batching** is enabled and `hibernate.order_inserts=true`. This leads to a foreign key violation. We have one transaction that creates a kind of model with a lot of different entities.
Everything is saved through cascading including the following entity that gives the foreign key violation:

```
public class PlanItemDefinition {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    private UUID id;

    ...

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "default_control_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_plan_item_definition_default_control_id"))
    private PlanItemControl defaultControl;

    ...

}


public class PlanItemControl {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    private UUID id;

    ...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "defaultControl")
    private PlanItemDefinition planItemDefinition;


    ...

}
```

Hibernate throws the following exception when the transaction commits:

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 1 insert into model.plan_item_definition 
(..., default_control_id, ...) values (..., '9572c4fc-4a1b-4747-878e-43d8ec8b8fd6'::uuid, ...) was aborted: ERROR: insert or update on table "plan_item_definition" violates foreign key constraint "fk_plan_item_definition_default_control_id"
  Detail: Key (default_control_id)=(9572c4fc-4a1b-4747-878e-43d8ec8b8fd6) is not present in table "plan_item_control".  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.BatchResultHandler.handleError(BatchResultHandler.java:169)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2286)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:521)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.internalExecuteBatch(PgStatement.java:870)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeBatch(PgStatement.java:893)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeBatch(PgPreparedStatement.java:1639)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeBatch(ProxyStatement.java:128)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:118)
    ... 123 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "plan_item_definition" violates foreign key constraint "fk_plan_item_definition_default_control_id"
  Detail: Key (default_control_id)=(9572c4fc-4a1b-4747-878e-43d8ec8b8fd6) is not present in table "plan_item_control".
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
    ... 130 more
```

When I remove `hibernate.order_inserts=true` everything works fine. This seems to be the same problem as https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9864?attachmentSortBy=dateTime but since we use hibernate version 5.2.17.Final this should be fixed?

### Question

Can somebody tell me if this is still a hibernate bug or something else we are doing wrong? Does hibernate not consider the order of insert statements in regard to cascading when `hibernate.order_inserts=true`?

Comment: Is your `@OneToOne` unidirectional or bidirectional ? Could you please also show your `PlanItemControl` entity.

Comment: Bidirectional, I've updated my question.

Comment: Could you please also show a mapping for the `PlanItemControl.id` field